# How to create a managed policy in cloudformation that allows lambda access to all s3 containers in an aws environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create a managed policy for a lambda that allows it access to all s3 buckets in my environment. This lambda basically scans the contents of each bucket and keys any object with the prefix archive/ if it older than thirty days.  I'm trying to create the policy in cloudformation but I keep getting a error when packaging that an end of the stream or document separator is expected. I know this is a yaml error but not sure exactly how to correct it.

```
 LambdaArchiveAccessPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties:
      ManagedPolicyName: LambdaArchiveAccessPolicy
      Description: Policy for allowing lambda to access s3 containers
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          Effect: Allow
          Action: 's3:*'
          Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::*'
```

I suspect how I am defining the resource is wrong. I'd appreciate any guidance or suggestions

Comment: Just added this policy to one of my stacks, minus the !Sub and was able to deploy it. As an aside your first indentation is 3 but the rest are 2; not sure if this is a copy/paste error or actual formatting issue, but if thats in your actual template this could be your issue, too.

Comment: that was it. missed the spacing by on. If you want to add that as the answer I'll give you credit for it

Comment: Great! Thank you! Glad it was helpful. Answer added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the YAML specification [here](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2777534), spacing is important in YAML files, and more specifically:

> All sibling nodes must use the exact same indentation level.

In your YAML your first line is indented three spaces, but subsequent indentation is only 2 spaces.  Correct the spacing by one and you will resolve your issue.